# Calling both object and function returning object

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i have tried some javascript code to bind two functions .My code is..

```
var b = {name: "sav",age: "20"}

var c = function() { 

return 5;

}

b.c({name: "oops",age: "12})
```

when i call something like this on the console ..I get the error `undefined is not a function`.

The thing is the i need to access the name property like `b.c.name`..If i call like `b.c.name` it must return `oops`..How can i do that ..why do i get error when i call `b.c({});`.

Hope you guys can help me ..Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "both" functions? There's only one. There is no association between `b` and `c` and so no `b.c`

Comment: sorry my mistake ..i have reedited

Comment: `c` is not a property of `b` so `b.c` does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b.c` doesn't exist, so it resolves to `undefined`.  `undefined` isn't a function, so that's where your error message is coming from.

Comment: can you just tell me how can i use like somevar.anothervaribale({});

Comment: Please make a code to make me understand in which situation i need to use somevar.anothervaribale({}); ..it would be really helpful ..Thanks

Comment: @user3600759: I'm not really sure what you're looking for, but here's a guess: `var b = {c: function(a) { return a.name; }};` `b.c({name:"oops"})`

Answer (score 2):

You're getting confused about the difference between an `Object` and a `Function`.

In your example, `b` is an `Object` with 2 properties, `name` and `age`.

When you write `b.c` you are trying to access a *property* of `b` named `c`, which doesn't exist, because `b` only has `name` and `age` properties.

Then, when you call `b.c({})` you are trying to call `b.c` as a `Function`, but since `b.c` doesn't exist, its value is `undefined` so it throws an error that you tried to call undefined as a function.

You can assign an `Object` to `c` as you did with `b` like so:

```
var c = {name: "oops",age: "12"};
```

Now you can access these properties like this:

```
c.name // this gives you 'oops' 
c.age  // this gives you '12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Dot notation is how you access properties and methods of objects. If what you want to do is simply pass data to a function, you don't need to use dot notation:

```
function doSomething(arg1, arg2, etc...) {
    // do stuff with passed args
}

b = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 25
}

doSomething(b);
```

If you need that function scoped to a specific object, you need to make it a method of the object:

```
b.doSomething = function() { //etc... }
```

or

```
b = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 25,
    getAge: function() {
        return b.age;
    }
}

b.getAge();
```